# iframe with src with same domain and port as the parent document is not editable/disabled

Tags: iframe, cross-domain

I have a url (http://localhost:8080/doc1.html) opened in the browser. I have an iframe with url (http://localhost:8080/doc2.html) within the parent document.

The links and forms in the iframe are not enabled. I am unable to click on a link or post the form.

I thought I am not violating the cross-origin policy. The links and form should work.

Comment: I am using  javascript to create the iFrame dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

i had set iframe_obj.style.pointerEvents = "none" as i was doing something on top of the iframe. Now i have set it to "auto" and is editable.